# Login-AzureRmAccount can't login to Azure using PSCredential

Tags: powershell, azure, authentication, credentials

I'm trying to login to my Azure account non-interactively from a script.
I just don't know why it fails:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@$$W0rd" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("script1234@outlook.com", $secpasswd)

Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount : Sequence contains no elements
```

Could anyone help me with this one please?

Thanks

Comment: Just a hunch: can you try by escaping reserved characters (like $)?

Comment: try putting the string in single quotes instead of double quotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atf's answer has a point but however, this is not only the issue. We cannot directly sign in non-interactively using Hotmail or Outlook account. You must use domain of your account to sign in.

See a similar issue posted in server fault : https://serverfault.com/questions/746557/add-azureaccount-unknown-user-type-unknown-user-type-on-azure-automation/746673

It mentions:

> Make sure the credential asset name (not username) is a simple string.
>   Also make sure the credential asset username is a valid OrgID user
>   (ex: abc@fdgdf.onmicrosoft.com), not a Microsoft / Live account
>   (joe@gmail.com).

Comment: that's right. I ended up creating a service principal to authenticate my script rather using my account. You cannot login non-intereractively to Azure using a Microsoft Live account.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing issue with the '$' character in your password P@$$W0rd

You need to introduce escape character (`) in order to retain the exact value. See the difference-

[image]

Hence your code look like this-

[image]

You can have a look in escape characters in powershell here - http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html

Comment: Actually, the password I'm using is not 'P@$$W0rd'. I just didn't want to show my real password so I made it up. My actual password doesn't have any '$' characters, but thanks a lot for pointing it out. My apologies for that.

Comment: For powershell you can't ignore such catch

Comment: I totally agree with you, I should have written 'exAmplePassword' or something similar to avoid any confusion.