# Add-AzureRmAccount : Sequence contains no elements

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to validate a script to connect to Azure via PowerShell.

```
$username = "asdfasdf"
$password = "asdfasdf"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId asdfasdf
```

Full error message:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount : Sequence contains no elements
At C:\Users\Martin\Documents\Tasks\Azure Script ARM API Syntax Conversion\Connect Azure V1.ps1:6 char:1
+ Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureRMAccountCommand
```

I saw here [Login-AzureRmAccount can't login to Azure using PSCredential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657391/login-azurermaccount-cant-login-to-azure-using-pscredential) that perhaps special characters may cause an error but I tried escaping the one `!` in my password without success. What else could be causing this problem?

Comment: Your account is a Micrsoft account (such as *.outlook.com and *.hotmail.com) ?

Comment: Yes it is a Microsoft account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This is an AD restriction, you cannot login non-interactively to Azure using a Microsoft Live account.** I tested in my lab, if my account is non-Microsoft account, I could login to Azure.

[image]