# Visual Studio Team Services: Sequence contains no elements

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I'm in the process of going through a Visual Studio Team Services build step. Everything appears to going until the build step **Azure Deployment**. At that step I get the error: Sequence contains no elements, see image below. Can someone let me know if they have seen this error before during a VSTS build? And how it was resolved?

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAgTI.png)

Thanks

Peter

Comment: The first hit for "PowerShell sequence contains no elements" indicates this could be related to the account you are using to authenticate to Azure (from your PowerShell script): "AD restriction, you cannot login non-interactively to Azure using a Microsoft Live account." Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608217/add-azurermaccount-sequence-contains-no-elements

Comment: @haschdl, thanks. You were correct. The problem was to with my credentials